# gaeutilities' session works on SDK, but not on Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, session

I encountered a strange problem: The gaeutilities' session worked on the GAE SDK, but not on the actual Google App Engine platform. The followings are session creation and existence checking  using Python, respectively.

Session creation:

```
self.session = sessions.Session()
self.session.delete_item('account')
self.session.delete_item('accountKey')
...
query = db.Query(model.Member)
query = query.filter('account =', account)  # 'account' is the user account
results = query.fetch(limit=1)
if results:  # Account exists
    member = results[0]
    self.session['account'] = account   
    self.session['accountKey'] = member.key()
...
```

Session existence checking:

```
self.session = sessions.Session()
if 'accountKey' in self.session:  # Session exists
    account = self.session['account']  # Could this be the problem?
...
```

The above program runs OK on the GAE SDK. But I uploaded the program to Google App Engine, and it didn't work. What might be the problem?

Comment: what's the actual error? Also try checking the len of 'results' rather then it's existence as (I seem to recall) it will return an empty list instead of none.

Comment: Checking the log (No idea that those means): Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMTLast-Modified: Fri, 28 Dec 12 14:04:14 UTCCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0Pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another approach to solve the problem using gae-sessions. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151821/1802305).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiair with gaeutilities. But with `self.session = sessions.Session()` you create a new session.  This will be empty. So your check `if 'accountKey' in ...` will not work. There must be another way to get the existing session.

Comment: Can somebody shed some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: I tried: if hasattr(self, 'session') and 'accountKey' in self.session: ...   --> not working

Comment: As far as I know, "self.session = sessions.Session()" either creates a new session, or gets the existent session.

Comment: OK, so you could show what is in the session with : logging.info(self.session) But is there a reason for using gaeutilities? The preferred method for GAE with Python 27 uses webapp2, which has well documented session functionality.

Comment: no particular reasons for using gaeutilities. I'll give webapp2's session a try. Thanks.

Comment: I tried GAE webapp2 sessions but failed. I've edited another question about what the correct process of creating and checking sessions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078054/gae-webapp2-session-the-correct-process-of-creating-and-checking-sessions). Would you care to take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: I have seen your new question. Did you follow the example, using dispatch and a webapp2 handler? Why would you like to delete the session? You can control the lifetime (maxage) of the cookie. If you like to delete the session, you can delete the cookie and skip the save session in the finally block, using a flag in the request registry.

Comment: I am not familiar with sessions. My understanding is: when a user logs in, create a session; when a particular function is invoked, check if a session exists, and if not, ask for logging in; and finally, when the user logs out, delete the session. Maybe you can correct me if I am wrong. Furthermore , I don't quite understand the documentation of webapp2's session. For example, where should we call the BaseHandler class? How do I use dispatch() and session() methods provided by BaseHandler? The concepts there are so few and even vague.

Comment: With webapp2 sessions, the session exists  during the lifetime of the app. In your case. You can only use the app, if you login, and the login will be  be registred in the session. Using a cookie with maxage, the session will end after some time. The basehandler class will be called by the handler, because this class overrides the dispatch method of the handler. So make an exact copy of this class, to use it.

Comment: I guess I have to do more research. One last question, I kept getting the error message: '...' object has no attribute 'session' when using self.session('...') and self.session.get('...'). Why?

Comment: I think the session store must be activated before your webapp2 request handler is dispatched. I will try to giive an example in your new question.